# Recyclerviews in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get this working: I basically want two Recyclerviews in one ViewPager. I followed this Tutorial: http://android-java-development.blogspot.de/2012/05/system.html, but it doesn't seem to work. I looks like the view pager is empty and the recycler view doesn't show up.

Here's my layout code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tab_height">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/accent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And my PageAdapter:

```
public class NewsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private Vector<RecyclerView> recyclerViewList;
    private String[] titles;

    public NewsPagerAdapter(Context context, int titlesId) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recyclerViewList = new Vector<>();

        setTitles(titlesId);
    }

    public void add(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerViewList.add(recyclerView);
    }

    public RecyclerView.Adapter getAdapterForViewAtIndex(int index) {
        return recyclerViewList.get(index).getAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        container.addView(recyclerViewList.get(position),
                new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100)
        );
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return recyclerViewList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    public void setTitles(int titles) {
        this.titles = context.getResources().getStringArray(titles);
    }
}
```

And my onCreatView method:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager1 = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.news_column_count));

GridLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.news_column_count));

RecyclerView listView1 = new RecyclerView(getActivity());
RecyclerView listView2 = new RecyclerView(getActivity());
listView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);
listView2.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);

NewsAdapter adapter1 = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), null);
NewsAdapter adapter2 = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), null);
adapter1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
adapter2.setOnItemClickListener(this);

listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

newsPagerAdapter.add(listView1);
newsPagerAdapter.add(listView2);

newsViewPager.setAdapter(newsPagerAdapter);
```

Here I'm passing the cursor object to the adapter:

```
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        ((NewsAdapter) newsPagerAdapter.getAdapterForViewAtIndex(0)).swapCursor(data);
    }
```

Comment: It seems to me that you missed the layout params for the RecyclerViews that you created programmatically. Try to use something like this `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);` for both of your views

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply! Unfortunately, the recycler view still seems to be invisible

Comment: ok, look at the adapter implementation

Comment: I would do two things but let me first ask you a question. Where are you populating the two RecyclerViews? As I see, you pass null as second parameter in the NewsAdapter (which I assume it is the collection). Am I right? Without having any items to render, RecyclerView will be empty (invisible)

Comment: Yeah, the adapter is a cursor adapter implementation. I basically start a loader and pass the results back to the adapter (I'll add the code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77534/discussion-between-zsolt-boldizsar-and-tobs).

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/tabs-with-swipe-views/#more-79

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to extend `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in order to easily embed RecyclerView. If you are going to update your ViewPager contents during its lifecycle it is strictly recommended to use **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**

You will have to create additional fragment layout, containing `RecyclerView`.

If you wish to update your `ViewPager` with `SwipeRefreshLayout`, don't wrap it with `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Instead, you must have `SwipeRefreshLayout` inside fragment layout.

Therefore for your fragment you may get the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/categoryList"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And create additional Fragment class, which will inflate that layout and implement methods, that you will need to update refresh indicator status.

A bit old example is found here:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

If you wish to connect your ViewPager with new support library TabLayout, it is easily one with:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Finally, if you will update your "fragmented" `ViewPager`, don't try to reset the adapter, as fragments are managed not with adapter, but with `FragmentManager`. It is wiser to update content of corresponding `RecyclerViews`

```
public class MyFragmentedPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private final SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener mRefreshListener;
    private Vector<PriceListFragment> fragmentList;
    private Vector<String> titles;

    public MyFragmentedPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, MyComplexData data, OnCartActionListener listener, TabLayout tabLayout, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener refreshListener) {
        super(fm);
        mTabLayout = tabLayout;

        // external refresh listener, that will trigger an updateData() 
        mRefreshListener = refreshListener;

        fragmentList = new Vector<>();
        titles = new Vector<>();
        updateData(data);
    }

    public void updateData(MyComplexData data) {
        boolean updateTabs = false;
        boolean hasNewData = false;

        Vector<String> newTitles = new Vector<>();

        int position = 0;
        for(TabContents tabContents : data.getTabContents()) {

            if(tabContents.getListContents() == null)
                continue;
            hasNewData = true;
            boolean isNewFragment;

            MyFragment fragment;
            try {
                fragment = fragmentList.get(position);
                isNewFragment = false;
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                fragment = new MyFragment();
                isNewFragment = true;
            }
            // Update the data, title and hide update indicator of SwipeRefreshLayout
            fragment.setTabContents(tabContents);

            newTitles.add(tabContents.getName());

            if(isNewFragment) {
                fragment.setRefreshListener(mRefreshListener);
                fragmentList.add(fragment);
            }
            position++;
        }

        if(!hasNewData)
            return;

        // we need to decide, whether to update tabs
        if(titles.size() != newTitles.size()) {
            updateTabs = true;
        } else {
            for(position = 0; position < titles.size(); position++) {
                if(!titles.get(position).equals(newTitles.get(position))) {
                    updateTabs = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        titles = newTitles;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        if(updateTabs)
            mTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    // You need to override this method as well
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) object;
        String title = (String) fragment.getTitle();
        int position = titles.indexOf(title);

        if (position >= 0) {
            return position;
        } else {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position).getTitle();
    }
}
```

Your `MyFragment` class has to implement `getTitle()` method.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer because thats the same conclusion i came to. I just thought it would be more efficient not to use fragments because I habe the same underlying dataset for all the views. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you. I posted that answer because I couldn't find any answer on that question for other men who will search it including myself in future =)

Comment: I had extends FragmentPagerAdapter and from days trying to find why RecyclerView doesnt update. After reading your reply  I have changed extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter and it worked .. Thank YOUU

Comment: You are welcome. That's incredible how such an old answer can still be useful :)