# Swipe down Fragment Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I trying to make a fragment appear by swiping down I'm using Viewpager but I only can swipe right or left, what I need is some similar like what Snapchat do They use fragments but they can be accessed by swiping in any direction (up down,right or left), here's the code what I am currently using it works perfectly to make the typical fragments movements (right and left) but I need to add something that make I can access a fragment by swiping down.

```
import ...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // FullScreen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new RegisterLogin();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new PrincipalPage();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new DevsArea();
                break;

        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}

}
```

and here's the XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.vs.versus.versus.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `RecyclerView` here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html

set the `RecyclerView` orientation to `VERTICAL` and make your item layout root `View` use `height="match_parent"`

last step, implement the `SnapHelper` or use the `LinearSnapHelper` directly and apply it to the `RecyclerView`

here the `SnapHelper`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SnapHelper.html

now you got a vertical `ViewPager`, well something akin to that.

Or, just use some other dudes project(s)

https://github.com/kaelaela/VerticalViewPager

https://github.com/chadguo/VerticalViewPager

If you need a full 4-direction swipe (left,right,top,down) wrap a vertical `RecyclerView` into a horizontal `ViewPager`

Comment: Thank you I will try that

Comment: I hope this is what you are looking for. If not, please tell me

Comment: I think the RecyclerView may help me bout the problem is that I don't know how to put a activity in a RecyclerView

Comment: Set the recyclerciew as layout for your activity

Comment: How I can do that? in the XML of my activity or in the java file of the activity?

Comment: I'm confused because I don't know how to implement the Recycler in my viewpager that is my problem

Comment: in the XML for your ViewPager Page layout.
oh okay, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171692/recyclerviews-in-viewpager for details, or google it, there is plenty information and how tos out there